# Как в selectRaw в качестве столбца указать 1?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
->selectRaw(select 1
        from users
        where users.id in (3, 5 ,7))
```

сейчас выдает ошибку column 1 not found

Comment: попробуй обернуть единицу в апострофы: ``select `1` from users``

Comment: и зачем это чудное надо?

Comment: Это нужно для условия.
if(1 = 1, 'Да', 'Нет') и вместо единицы вставляется вот этот запрос

Comment: чую тут костыли какие-то. распишите задачу чуть подробнее что вы делаете.

Comment: if((select 1 from users where users.id in (3, 5 ,7)) limit 1) = 1, 'Да', 'Нет')
Примерно так